# Table stuck when delete matching records within another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a **table A** having around 15 millions of records. I have a process which delete and insert data into **table A** from another temp **table B**.

It was working good and another user does not access this **table A** directly. The process scenario is - 
1) delete all matching records from **table A** with **table B**. 
2) Insert new fresh data into **table A** from **table B**.

But sometime process is going to stuck. I have checked it but did not get any solution.

A) So, I have created new table in place of **table A** and fetch the old data into new table from **table A**. After sometime, I got the same issue with new table.

B) Next time, I have created another table in place of **table A** but did not insert old records in this table. Now, process is working fine.

But I need a solution to put all records in the **table A**. 
**Please,Can anybody help on it?**

I'm using **SQL Server 2005 Enterprise version**. This process is done via **store procedure**. Table does not have any index. There is only simply delete and insert only.

Comment: Sounds to me like the table is simply too large.  I think you'll need to give more information (what version of SQL, are the tables indexed and if so how, what is the SQL code you're using for this process, etc).

Comment: This question is almost impossible to answer unless you at least mention the RDBMS you're using.

Comment: We are using SQL Server 2005 with enterprise version. This process is done via store procedure. Table does not have any index. There is only simply delete and insert only

Comment: Another thing, we have another table which are containing more than 60 millions of records and using the same scenario. I'm not getting any issue with them.

Comment: Add more information to your question, table schemas, indexes, the query you are trying.

Answer (score 0):

I think the buffer is becoming full when you are working with large amount of data.To flush the buffer, use `COMMIT` statement after a certain amount of `inserts` are performed which cause the data in the buffer to be written into the disk.

Comment: Hi Bishnu,Thanks for the suggestion. But main issue is, table A is going to stuck when matching records are going to delete. at the same time, when I try to select top 1 * from table A then query goes to run for such a long time. if I try to select top 1 * from table A with (nolock) then result comes in a second. I'm not able to find out the issue.

Comment: Another thing, This steps takes only 20-30 seconds to complete the process. If above problem comes then it can be run more than 2 days without any result. What would be the issue?

Comment: @MukeshSingh - The above comment just sounds like lock escalation. As you are on Enterprise Edition you might want to look at partitioning. This allows you to switch data in and out of the table as a simple metadata change.

Comment: @MartinSmith - Thank you for the suggestion. I'm going through this option also. Can you please give me some examples on it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, problem with the database end.
As I observed, If your database is going to large then you need to monitor you database and run maintenance jobs to remove any inconsistency from your database.